# Chrome - pound sign in URL makes page jump to bottom

Tags: google-chrome

I noticed that in Chrome, when there's a pound sign at the end of the URL the page sometimes jumps to the bottom (depending on the page). Here's an example:

This is a version of the page that snaps to the bottom in Chrome:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp#

And this one does not:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Is there any idea of what's going on here? The website I'm developing is behaving the same way.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this has to do with the existence of iframes.  I don't know of a solution other than don't link to just `#`

Comment: Part of the issue is that I'm using <form action="#"> for submission - when I redirect the # is preserved, and I'm going to the bottom of the page. I don't want to have to put hash-stripping javascript on every page, but maybe I'll have to.

Comment: Why do you have `action="#"` anyway?

Comment: Just did some looking around and it looks like I can just remove the [action=] entirely - so it doesn't really explain exactly what's going on, but it does solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existence of the `#` focuses iframes.  This may be a browser bug, but the only workaround is to either not leave the fragment empty or remove it altogether.  `<form>`s used to require an action, but [there's nothing in the current HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element) that indicates that `<form>` requires an action.  Leaving off the action will cause a page to submit to the current url.